# `npx create-react-app` says it requires "Node 14 or higher" but I'm running 17.4.0. How can I fix this?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, create-react-app

I'm trying to start a new React project on my Mac (running Mojave 10.14.5).

In VS Code's Terminal I ran `npx create-react-app my-app` and got a message saying that my version of Node was out of date. I updated node to version 17.4.0 and ran it again - still got the same message.

I then ran clear cache: `npm cache clean --force` and tried again - still no luck.

`node -v` says I'm running 17.4.0.

Would anyone know what I could do?

Comment: nvm use 14, other words, try another version of the node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to uninstall the create-react-app and then npm install it again.
You can use these commands for uninstalling the create-react-app:
if you are using NPM:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

if you are using Yarn:

```
yarn global remove create-react-app
```

for creating new app you can use the following command:

```
npx create-react-app@latest your-project-name
```

You must notice that the create-react-app should not be installed globally as it is documented in [Create-React-app Docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#quick-start).

Also please note that it is safe to say, always use the LTS version of node (that is 16.13.2 at this time).

It should solve your problem with initiating a new react app.